# Abrir site pelo Google dá erro 500

Tags: google

Quando eu abro meu site pela busca do Google, ele acessa a página e dá o erro 500, porém, quando acessada a URL diretamente (a mesma url em outra aba), o site abre normal. O quê está acontecendo?

Site: royalechinelos.com.br

Busca Google: royale chinelos

Comment: Se você por o http:// na frente ele cria um link automaticamente

Comment: Já viu o log? **More information about this error may be available in the server error log.** ; creio que possa ter algo a ver com algum header na requisição não esperado que o redirecionamento do Google manda

Comment: Com certeza é alguma coisa em teu framework ou script no lado back-end do site que esta executando algo quanto tem o header Referer, sem código não tem como deduzir nada mais. Por favor forneça detalhes.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não tenho acesso ao arquivo de log no momento, por isso estou trocando de Host. Mas enquanto não posso fazer a migração, gostaria de encontrar uma solução.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não utilizo nenhum framework e em nenhuma parte do código eu utilizo o header Referer, somente o location, mas não especificamente na página inicial (index.php) e sim em outra

Comment: Acredito que deve ser cagada no provedor isso, pq estava funcionando normalmente e acho que desde ontem ou hj aconteceu isso.. e não mexo no código desde fevereiro..

Comment: Erro 500 é dentro do servidor, vc tentou trocar o index.php por um script mais vazio como `<?php echo 'olá mundo'; ?>`, se ainda ocorrer o problema então é porque o problema pode ser no Apache. Faça o teste por favor.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é, fiz o teste e dá o mesmo erro 500. Certeza que é cagada do provedor..

Comment: Por desencargo de consciência, baixe o log de erros do Apache e do PHP, se puder pegue somente o da ultima hora e então envie via pastebin.com

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como dito anteriormente, nesse provedor não tenho acesso aos arquivos de log, por isso estou efetuando a migração :/

Comment: Qual hospedagem usa? É possivel usar o PHP para baixar pelo nemos o log do proprio PHP, mesmo na hospedagem que uso o qual não tenho acesso foi possivel baixar usando PHP, o `phpinfo` informa a localização do log PHP e você pode tentar ler com `file_get_contents`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento parece que o problema era no provedor mesmo, ontem fiz a migração para o novo e o problema desapareceu. Obrigado a todos pela atenção

Comment: Pode ser que sim, ou então o problema era um modulo que não estava ativo no primeiro provedor e no segundo já é ativo, então o primeiro causava a falha justamente pela necessidade do modulo, o que talvez pudesse ser ativado.

Answer (score 2):

A diferença entre uma requisição direta e uma via Google é que no segundo caso o cabeçalho `Referer` é adicionado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sem maiores informações, eu investigaria o processamento desta entrada no cabeçalho.